# I need a formula for every 3 letter combination

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need a google spreadsheet formula that will produce every 3 letter combination.

However, I do not want any of the combinations to have duplicate or repeating letters

and

There needs to be atleast 1 vowel in each combinations.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does it matter where the vowels appear? Could an entry be *all* vowels? Does the resulting string need to be phonetically pronounceable? It would help if you tell us the big-picture goal (i.e., *Why* do you need this? *What will you do* with it once you have it?).

Comment: The vowels can be anywhere and yes it could be all vowels ex. AEO

Comment: Do you consider the semi-vowel `Y` to satisfy the condition as a vowel, or only `A|E|I|O|U`?

Comment: And do you realize that this will result in over 7600 combinations (8700+ if you count 'Y' as a vowel)?

Comment: The vowels can be anywhere and yes it could be all vowels ex. AEO
The string does not have to be pronounceable.
I have this game I play, and I create alot of characters in this game. I prefer 3-letter names. But this game is so old that almost every 3 letter name has been taken up at some point in the 30+ years it has been established. But there is a way I can use a script to see if character names are available. But I need the data to add to the script. The game does require you to have atleast 1 vowel in the name. They do allow duplicate letters but my preferance is to not use duplicates.

Comment: Yes I know it would be in the 1000s. All combinations without without any filters is around 17000 something.

Comment: For this situation we can consider Y as a normal vowel like the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))&IF(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))=TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))),"~",TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26)))))&IF(REGEXMATCH(FLATTEN(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))&IF(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))=TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))),"~",TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))))),TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26)))),"~",TRANSPOSE(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(26))))),"WHERE NOT Col1 CONTAINS '~' AND (Col1 CONTAINS 'A' OR Col1 CONTAINS 'E' OR Col1 CONTAINS 'I' OR Col1 CONTAINS 'O' OR Col1 CONTAINS 'U' OR Col1 CONTAINS 'Y')"))`

The short version of how it works:

A virtual column of every letter A-Z is concatenated with a virtual row of every letter A-Z. (These are `SEQUENCE`d as ASCII codes using the `CHAR` function.) Where a duplicate is found in this process, the `~` symbol is used as a temporary placeholder, to assure all results have two components. The resulting 2D grid of strings is `FLATTEN`ed into one column and the process is repeated exactly against a row of A-Z, replacing duplicates with `~`, to assure all results now have three components. The resulting 2D grid is *again* `FLATTEN`ed into one column. Then `QUERY` keeps only entries that *do not* have an instance of `~` and that *do* have an instance of one of the six vowels.

Comment: Assuming this accomplishes what I say it does (and it does), please mark the post "Best Answer" to alert the volunteer contributor community here that the issue has already been fully resolved. Thanks.

Comment: thank you alot this helped me greatly.